# favicon wont show up on any of my pages

Tags: html

```
<head>
<meta(charset='utf-8')>
<link rel="shortcut icon" type="image/x-icon" href="http://viewwit.com/image/favicon.ico" />
</head>
```

the head of my site starts with this but the favicon still won't show up inside of the title bar on any of my pages.

if you want to check for yourself the site is http://viewwit.com/ (I know it's bad, I'm making it just for fun).

I can't figure out why it isn't working. Any help would be awesome.

Comment: Your site isn't bad mate, it's cool.

Comment: @Roberrrt thanks! It's basically a reddit ripoff is mostly what's bad about it though, just doing it to get more familiar with web design :)

Comment: It works, it that green eye with a white background.

Comment: Add your favicon image file to your websites root directory and that should work. Some browsers disregard the in-code icon tag and immediately look within the folder for it. Also some browsers cache favicon file (or lack of) and require a soft reload to begin showing.

Comment: Try to force-reload by pressing `ctrl` + `shift` + `r`

Comment: @N.J.Dawson *hard reload

Comment: @VDWWD you're right, it seems to be working on internet explorer for me now, but chrome still shows nothing even with force refreshes hard refreshes and incognito mode. As long as it's only for me it's fine though so thank you!

Comment: @noahnu I was not directly refering to the "normal/hard/emply cache and reload" options, otherwise I would have mentioned normal instead of soft. Restarting the browser is enough to get the favicon

Answer (score -1, accepted):

As an easy fix, you can place your favicon within the root directory (same place as index.html). This is the default location which a browser will look for when searching for a favicon.

Comment: Most browsers look for the favicon.ico at the root first, but as far as I'm aware, they all read the tag. Which browsers have issues?

Comment: @noahnu I was operating on that my browser did not work but another user had mentioned it worked in Internet Explorer, which I assumed was the combination of the "shortcut icon" rel instead of just "icon". Eitherway, edit my answer if you believe it can be explained better.

Comment: Not sure how accurate this is, but it mentions precedence of the linked favicon over the root in most modern/popular browsers: [Wikipedia Favicon](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Favicon#How_to_use)

Comment: @noahnu I also looked around, but you seem to be more clued up than I, so if you feel the answer could be improved then you're welcome to do so.

Comment: I _don't_ have an answer for the OP. From personal experience I like using both root/linked which is why I up-voted your original comment. I do believe this answer though (which is marked as correct) is factually wrong.

Comment: I was answering from previous experience and observations - as I said one user mentioned it working in their specific browser but I personally could not see it and neither could OP. I assume the fact it was marked correct this solved the issue. I'll remove the bits you have an issue with, but as previously stated I'm not an expert and am not in a position to elaborate as to why other than the usage of "shortcut" within the rel attribute.

Answer (score 0):

Try these

```
<meta charset="utf-8">
<link rel="shortcut icon" href="http://viewwit.com/image/favicon.ico" />
```

Take a look at the meta charset